# How to find the first value in a column larger than the previous value in the column

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula to return the index of the first value in a large column such that `ABS((COL)(ROW)-(COL)(ROW+2))< 0.1`

Clearly, this is pretty easy to program in VBA by starting with the first row in the column and iterating through. However, I'm just looking for an excel formula in this case.

I think it will need to be something functionally like:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(TRUE,($A$1:$A$100)-($A$3:$A$102)<.1,0))
```

This clearly won't return anything. I'm interested in how to do that subtraction part using excel formulas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add the ABS and ARRAY ENTER the formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(TRUE,ABS(($A$1:$A$100)-($A$3:$A$102))<.1,0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode. If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize I was so close! Thanks, Scott